# Error en alert, javascript y html no aparece nada en alert

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function btn() {

  window.location.href = "index.html";
  var precioP = document.getElementById('precioP').value;
  var nombreP = document.getElementById('nombreP').value;



  if (precioP == "" || nombreP == "") {
    alert("achu, los datos son obligatorios achu!");
    return false;
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="index">
  <form action="alta.php" method="GET">
    <FIELDSET>
      <center>
        <LEGEND><b>Alta producto</b></LEGEND>
        <hr><br><br>
        <label>Nombre del producto</label><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="nombreP" id="nombreP"><br><br>
        <label>Precio producto</label><br><br>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="precioP" id="precioP"><br><br>
        <button style="width:50%" id="btn" onclick="btn()">GUARDAR DATOS</button>
      </center>
    </FIELDSET>
  </form>
</div>
```

Cuando lo corro y no escribo nada no me sale el alert, es como si no se hubieran conectado bien.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta, intenta explicarnos mejor lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: window.location.href="index.html";  estas renviando al index antes de hacer cualquier operación, eso pasalo al último o quita esa línea

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo se la quite pero sigue igual. quiero que al no ingresar ningun dato me muestre ese alert de mensaje

Answer (score 0):

El código JavaScript lo tienes que poner dentro de la etiqueta script

```
<script>
    function btn() {

        window.location.href="index.html"; 
        var precioP=document.getElementById('precioP').value;
        var nombreP=document.getElementById('nombreP').value;

        if (precioP=="" || nombreP=="") {
            alert ("achu, los datos son obligatorios achu!");
            return false;
       }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que hay un conflicto con los nombres, al hacer esto

```
<button style="width:50%" id="btn" onclick="btn()">GUARDAR DATOS</button>
```

El `id` y la función tienen el mismo nombre y esto puede causar conflictos en algunos navegadores, cambia el nombre del `id` o de la función.

Agregué el `type=button` para que no envíe la form de manera automática

```js
function btnFunc() {
  var precioP = document.getElementById('precioP').value;
  var nombreP = document.getElementById('nombreP').value;
  if (precioP == "" || nombreP == "") {
    alert("achu, los datos son obligatorios achu!");
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="index">
  <form action="alta.php" method="GET">
    <FIELDSET>
      <center>
        <LEGEND><b>Alta producto</b></LEGEND>
        <hr><br><br>
        <label>Nombre del producto</label><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="nombreP" id="nombreP"><br><br>
        <label>Precio producto</label><br><br>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="precioP" id="precioP"><br><br>
        <button type="button" style="width:50%" id="btn" onclick="btnFunc()">GUARDAR DATOS</button>
      </center>
    </FIELDSET>
  </form>
```